# CSS 3D contact icons

Tags: css

I was playing arround with some CSS and ended up in making some 3D hover icons with font awesome.

I wanted to ask for some feedback on my CSS: Best-practices, any other comments, maybe bad things that you should not do...

```css
article {
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 min-height: 100%;
}

article h2{
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.intro-contact {
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.ul_icons {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.ul_icons .li_icons {
 position: relative;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 0 30px;
 transform: rotate(-30deg) skew(25deg);
 background: #ccc;
}

.ul_icons .li_icons span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #000;
 transition: 0.5s;
 display: flex !important;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 30px !important;
}

.ul_icons .li_icons:hover span:nth-child(5) {
 transform: translate(40px, -40px);
 opacity: 1;
}
.ul_icons .li_icons:hover span:nth-child(4) {
 transform: translate(30px, -30px);
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.ul_icons .li_icons:hover span:nth-child(3) {
 transform: translate(20px, -20px);
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.ul_icons .li_icons:hover span:nth-child(2) {
 transform: translate(10px, -10px);
 opacity: 0.4;
}
.ul_icons .li_icons:hover span:nth-child(1) {
 transform: translate(0, 0);
 opacity: 0.2;
}

.ul_icons .li_icons:nth-child(1) span {
 background: #3b5999;
}
.ul_icons .li_icons:nth-child(2) span {
 background: #87CEEB;
}
.ul_icons .li_icons:nth-child(3) span {
 background: #E3D094;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <section id="main" class="intro_contact no-mobile">
   <article>
    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <ul class="ul_icons">
     <li class="li_icons">
       <a href="#mail">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </a>
     </li>
     <li class="li_icons">
       <a href="#phone">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </a>
     </li>
     <li class="li_icons">
       <a href="#personal">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </article>
   </section>
```